# Left R-module definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am reading Paolo Aluffi's textbook [*Algebra: Chapter 0*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Algebra-Chapter-Graduate-Studies-Mathematics/dp/0821847813) and am just a little bit confused about the difference between left and right modules using his first definition. He defines the left-$R$ module as an abelian group $M$ together with a ring homomorphism $\sigma : R \rightarrow\text{Hom}_{\text{Ab}}(M,M)$. This makes sense to me, but then I don't understand the distinction between a left $R$-module and a right $R$-module using this definition.

I am guessing that a left $R$-module is defined as above, while a right $R$-module is defined as an abelian group $M$ together with a ring homomorphism
$\phi : R^{\circ} \rightarrow\text{Hom}_{\text{Ab}}(M,M)$, where $R^{\circ}$ is the opposite ring of $R$ obtained by reversing the order of multiplication?

Comment: That's exactly correct! Good work.

Comment: @AlexWertheim Thank you for your answer!